# How to write data back to storage?

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

I have a method called `changePlaceName` and i know it is working but after i call `getPlaces` to see the changes, i don't see the new place name instead i see the name when i created a new place.

this is `changePlaceName`

```js
export function changePlaceName(placeId: u32, placeName: PlaceName): void {
  assert(placeId >= 0, 'Place ID must be >= 0');
  const place = Place.find(placeId);
  logging.log(place.name);  //gives "Galata Tower"
  place.name = placeName;
  logging.log(place.name);  // gives "New Galata Tower"
}
```

I need to save it somehow but I don't know how to do it.

I also tried this way;

```js
export function changePlaceName(placeId: u32, placeName: string): void {
    assert(placeId >= 0, 'Place ID must be >= 0');
    const place = Place.find(placeId);
    logging.log(place.name);
    place.name = placeName;
    let newPlace = storage.get<string>(placeName, 'new galata tower');
    storage.set<string>(placeName, newPlace);
    logging.log('New place is now: ' + newPlace);
}
```

Now my visual code is complaining about the `newPlace` inside the `storage.set`

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're using some kind of class to manage the concept of "Place", why not add an instance method to that class to `save()` the place once you've changed it's name?

would help if you also posted your code for `Place` here, by the way

my guess is that it looks something like this?

!note: this is untested code

```js
@nearBindgen
class Place {
  private id: number | null
  private name: string

  static find (placeId: number): Place {
    // todo: add some validation for placeId here
    const place = places[placeId]
    place.id = placeId
    return place
  }

  // here is the instance method that can save this class
  save(): bool {
    places[this.id] = this
  } 
}

// a collection of places where placeId is the index
const places = new PersistentVector<Place>("p")
```

Comment: Thank you Sherif and Willem. I can now save data back to storage!

Answer (score 2):

What is the code of `Place.find`? I assume you are using a persistent map under the hood.

Is there a `Place.set`?  You need to store the Place back to the same key used to find it.